# Screen goes black with NO SIGNAL message after installing Nvidia Driver-390

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in new Assembled PC. When I installed Nvidia-390 or 396 driver for Nvidia Quadro P2000 and rebooted the system, the Login screen goes black with NO SIGNAL after successful boot (Ubuntu logo screen).

My system configuration is:

- Mother Board - Gigabyte GA-H170MDS3H,
- Processor - Intel i5 7th Gen,
- RAM - 8 GB DDR4,
- Hard Disk - 1 TB,
- Graphics Card - Nvidia Quadro P2000

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is discussed on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1773113

You can subscribe to notifications about the bug there and/or mark it as affecting you too.